# What is the meaning of "... to felicit you ..."

Tags: word-usage

Recently I have received some comments about my work, and it used "... felicit you and your work".

What is the meaning of this word?

Is is positive or negative?

Comment: Did you look in a dictionary or two? If you looked but couldn't find it, did you notice [*felicitations*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/felicitation)?

Comment: Incorrect back-formation from *felicitation.*

Comment: Latin’s *felix* and it derivations gave us two happy (and happifying) verbs here, of which the more common one is *felicitate* from *fēlīcitātem* < *fēlīcitāre*, and the less common one is *felicify* from *fēlīcificāre*.  Our noun *felicity* also came from *fēlīcitātem*, but not without first have taken a rather long holiday in France, where *félicité* was the rule. *?Felicit* sounds like something pro-bono attorneys do — or Catwoman.

Comment: Two points: 1. You should ask the person who made the comment. We can only guess what they meant. 2. The end of a sentence is not enough context to derive the meaning of a word. The whole sentence is required (possibly more), otherwise we are just guessing what is meant.

Comment: Just to back up what Matt says - we can speculate about what they meant by this non-word but it'll only ever be speculation. It's not impossible that it's a typo or malapropism (for something like "facilitate" perhaps). Seeing as it's a non-word, the only possible issue I can see is that you might embarrass them. But against that, if you ask tactfully then they might well be grateful to have had the mistake pointed out for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Felicit" does not appear to be an English word in itself, however the closest word is "felicity" -- great happiness, something that is pleasing or well-chosen.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/felicity

It might be possible that the commenter incorrectly derived felicit from felicity, as one might extract "congratulate" from "congratulations". In which case, he might have meant that he "delights in you and your work", which is a good thing.

Is the commenter, to your knowledge, a native speaker of English?

*One other possibility is that it is a typo of "elicit", meaning to "draw out, or evoke", though it does not make a lot of sense when applied to "you and your work".

Answer (score 1):

The verb [felicitate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/felicitate) exists, defined by The Free Dictionary:

> fe·lic·i·tate;  fəˈlisəˌtāt
>   verb
>   *verb* **felicitate** *3rd person present* **felicitates** *past tense* **felicitated** *past participle* **felicitated** *gerund or present participle* **felicitating**.
>
> 1. To offer congratulations to: "I felicitate you on your memory, sir" (John Fowles).
> 2. *Archaic* To make happy.

It appears that *felicit* is a clipped form of the verb *felicitate* or a type of [malapropism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malapropism).

Comment: and the expression 'Felicitations', but far less common than 'Congratulations'.